# jQuery: ajax runs both handlers - done and fail

Tags: jquery

I have an `ajax` call like

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'addVideo',
        data: {
            video_title: title,
            playlist_name: playlist,
            url: id
            // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
        done: bootstrap_alert.success('video saved successfully'),
        fail: bootstrap_alert.error('There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while')
    });
```

and actions as

```
// setting up alerts on action
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.success = function(message) {
  $('#feature').prepend('<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>');
}
bootstrap_alert.error = function(message) {
  $('#feature').prepend('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>');
}
```

When the front end makes ajax call, I see both the notifications at the same time

```
video saved successfully
There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while
```

Is that I am not making the ajax call correctly?

**UPDATE**
changing `done` to `success` results in same behavior

```
// send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addVideo',
            data: {
                video_title: title,
                playlist_name: playlist,
                url: id
                // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: bootstrap_alert.success('video saved successfully'),
            fail: bootstrap_alert.error('There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while')
        });
```

The server response is `HTTP/1.0" 200 3200`, I believe the `fail` shouldn't get called

Comment: Are you sure `$('#feature')` isn't modified by another part of your code?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The values are expected to be functions, *callbacks*. But, what you are doing is calling them right away. Wrap your callbacks around in anonymous functions.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'addVideo',
  data: { video_title: title, playlist_name: playlist, url: id }
}).done(function(){
  bootstrap_alert.success('video saved successfully');
}).fail(function(){
  bootstrap_alert.error('There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

`done` is always called. That's supposed to happen. You should be handling your success code in the `success` property.

Comment: In other words, `done` is used for when you need to do something whether the request failed or not, like removing a loading indicator from the screen

Comment: but fail shouldn't be called on ` HTTP/1.0" 200 3200` response, isn't it?

Comment: changing the `done` to `success` still results in same behavior

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it in an anonymous function (as others have noted). But, I haven't seen anyone mention why (which I think is worth mentioning).

The reason you need to do this is because javascript assigns the evaluation of the right side of the colon to the left side. In order to evaluate the right side it needs to run your function first. However if you have an anonymous function on the right side, it defines the function itself as the value of the reference on the left-side (in javascript the value of a variable can be a function) and assigns the function as is to the left side (which is now a reference to the function). So, it delays evaluation (running the function) until your ajax call completes.

Answer (score 1):

changing like this worked

```
// send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addVideo',
            data: {
                video_title: title,
                playlist_name: playlist,
                url: id
                // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                 // log a message to the console
                 console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
                 bootstrap_alert.success('video saved successfully');
            },

            // callback handler that will be called on error
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // log the error to the console
                console.log("The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown);
                bootstrap_alert.error('There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while');
            },
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `done` with `success` and `fail` with `error`? You're using them as options while they are callback hooks.